# Tactile switches

Tags: pcb, switches

I am trying to figure out how to remove a tactile switch and replace it will a wire to connect to a larger switch farther away from the PCB.
I am having trouble determining how I need to wire this. My thought right now is to remove the switch, solder a wire between where the 1 and 2 pins would be and do the same between the 3 and 4 pins.
Then run a wire from the 2 lines to hook up to a the switch farther away.
I have googled and watch a lot of YouTube videos but none of them answer if this can be done.
Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Normally tactile switches are N.O. momentary and have 2 or 4 pins, with the latter more popular. The 4 pins are internally connected in pairs. So you only need to connect to two of the pins.

There may be no reason to remove the old switch, simply connect the remote one in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Ok that sounds alot easier. So just to make sure I understand correctly just soder the wire to the 2 separate pins and run it to an new switch without having to remove the switch on the PCB board correct?

Comment: Correct. In the above schematic use 1 or 2 for one connection and 3 or 4 for the other connection to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That solves the biggest problem I had with my set up!